# Правильное перенаправление .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Есть много старых ссылок типа:

```
example.com/old_Supercontent/
example.com/old_Ultracontent/
example.com/old_Megacontent/
example.com/old_Gigacontent/
```

как их правильно перенаправить на на

```
example.com/new_Supercontent/
example.com/new_Ultracontent/
example.com/new_Megacontent/
example.com/new_Gigacontent/
```

соответственно? Можно ли написать одной строчкой сразу для всех? Или нужно на каждую писать отдельное правило?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно через `RewriteEngine` и все адреса с `old_*` перенаправлять на `new_*`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^old\_([A-Za-z]+)/?$ example.com/new_$1/ [L]
```